# Visual Studio Database Creation Failure

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I've been following this Microsoft documentation here (https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part4) on how to create a basic database for a .NET solution. I have Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition.

I fail to create a databse connection given the following error;

[image]

Here's notable system environment information;

[image]

And the version of the LocalDB file inside that 130\Tools\Binn ( or the 120);

[image]

Which is consistent with my Database connections options in Visual Studio;

[image]

Can someone tell me what is going on? This source here (https://www.codeproject.com/tips/1042100/how-to-resolve-the-data-source-value-in-the-connec) which I followed for a solution failed me. Thank you

EDIT: Is truly no one able to answer this question? If I haven't provided enough detail, please ask.

Comment: When you look at services Sql Server does (Sqlexpress) appear?

Comment: What will that do? And as far as naming a server in the first image, isn't that arbitrary? The author just used a naming convention or no? The error doesn't seem to point to there. Thank you for your reply I'd like some help on this

Comment: You're telling the "Add Connection" panel to look at `.\SQLEXPRESS` whereas your Database is actually called `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`. In other words, you don't have MSSQL Express installed, or an instance called SQLEXPRESS on your machine.

Comment: That worked, thanks Colin. I didn't realize server name is for an existing file.